# joda time ISO DateTime formatting

Tags: scala, datetime, jodatime, isodate

I'm using joda time to format my ISO Date input string, but I'm getting an exception that my ISO Date is malformed:

```
Invalid format: "2014-06-20T11:41:08+02:00" is malformed at "+02:00"
```

This is my code:

```
val formatter: DateTimeFormatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault)
val date: DateTime = formatter.parseDateTime("2014-06-20T11:41:08+02:00")
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: The data format string is "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSSZ". Hence you need a dot (".") and three digits between the seconds and the time zone. The three digits are mandatory and represent the milliseconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error comment is slightly misleading here, as Joda formatter you derive from `ISODateTimeFormat` expects the millisecond part of the date/time string to be present, therefore the following will work fine:

```
val formatter: DateTimeFormatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault())
val date: DateTime = formatter.parseDateTime("2014-06-20T11:41:08.0+02:00")
```

Answer (score 4):

The [answer by Radyk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24324657/642706) is correct.

## ISO 8601 Formats Built-In

However, you needn't specify a formatter at all. The [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class has a **built-in parser** for your [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant format, used automatically by the [constructor](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime-java.lang.Object-).

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "2014-06-20T11:41:08+02:00", timeZone );
```

While the second argument is optional, I suggest you assign a [DateTimeZone](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html) object to be assigned to the DateTime if you know such a time zone. The input string has an offset-from-UTC, but a time zone is more than just an offset. A time zone includes rules for [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) and other anomalies. Use [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), never 3 or 4 letter codes like `EST` or `IST`.

## Other Formats

You can apply many other formats:

- Built-in [ISO 8601 formatters](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html)
- Built-in [localized](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#forStyle-java.lang.String-) (short, medium, long, and full formats, [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html)-sensitive)
- [Custom specified by you](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#forPattern-java.lang.String-).

For example, if you want only the date portion without the time-of-day in your String representation, call [`ISODateTimeFormat.date()`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#date--) to access a built-in formatter.

Example code in Joda-Time 2.8.

```
String output = ISODateTimeFormat.date().print( dateTime );  // Format: yyyy-MM-dd
```

Search StackOverflow for hundreds of other Questions and Answers about formatting date-time values.

Comment: thanks for your answer. is there a way to print exactly this format with joda datetime?

Comment: The same built-in formatter is used by default in a DateTime's `toString` method. `String output = dateTime.toString();` if you want Strings generated in other formats, explore the `DateTimeFormat` class including the `forPattern` and `forStyle` methods and ISODateTimeFormat subclass.